# Shape segmentation using Depth-First-Search

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search

How to solve this in Depth-First-Search:

- 6x6 squares, cut along the edges of the lattice into two parts.
- The shape of the two parts is required to be exactly the same.

**Try to calculat**e: There are a total of how many different segmentation methods.

**Note**: Rotational symmetry belongs to the same segmentation method.

---

For example:

[image]

---

Sorry, it looks like I'm just looking for an answer without thinking. Actually, I think a lot. The original title didn't require a Depth-First-Search, and I think it needs to be used to solve this problem, but I don't have a clear idea. I think that meet the requirements is between grid is continuous, but I don't know how to express this kind of situation.

Comment: What have **you** tried so far? Show us **your** code / findings!

Comment: Questions asking for *homework help* **must** include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it ([help], [ask]).

Comment: Sorry, I have modified the description.

Comment: Please post the answer as an answer to your own question, rather than as part of the question.

Comment: See [here](https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/LWkyIxJUVR) a modified version of the answer posted. The solution assumes that "border line" between two symmetrical segments must go through the center and end in the circumference. It sounds logical to me. If you run the code in the ink with `N=2` (3x3 grid) you'll see in the printout that it does not find all segmentation. I think it needs to tested with 8 directions (including diagonal movements) : `int dir[][] = {{-1,0},{1,0},{0,-1},{0,1},{-1,-1}, {1,1},{-1, 1},{1,-1} };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the idea to use dfs is good. You could start the search on a clear (no walls) maze. 
Start the search on an arbitrary cell. 
For each cell explored : mark the symmetric one as "wall".

A pseudo code to find one segmentation could be:

```
    boolean dfs(cell) {

        if cell is not empty or was explores or null - return false
        symCell = get Symetric Cell of cell

        if symCell is not empty or was explores or null - return false
        else mark symCell as wall

        mark cell as explored   

       //loop over neighbors
       for(Cell c : getNeighbors of cell){
          if ( dfs(c) )   return true
       }

       return false
    }
```

The process can be repeated over and over again to find more segmentations.
I did not come up yet with any good idea about a stop criteria: how do you know that all possible segmentations were found. 
Here is a simple java swing demonstration of finding **one** segmentation:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SwingMaze extends JFrame {

    private JPanel mazePanel;
    private Cell[][] cells;
    private int mazeRows = 6, mazeCols = 6; //default size

    public SwingMaze() { this(null); }
    public SwingMaze(Cell[][] cells) {

        this.cells = (cells == null) ?
                getCells(mazeRows,mazeCols) : cells;
        mazeRows = this.cells.length; mazeCols = this.cells[0].length;
        setTitle("Grid");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        buildUi();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    void buildUi() {

        mazePanel = new JPanel();
        mazePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(cells.length, cells[0].length));
        add(mazePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        for (Cell[] cellsRow : cells) {
            for (Cell cell : cellsRow) {
                cell.addMouseListener(cellMouseListener(cell));
                mazePanel.add(cell);
            }
        }

        add(new JLabel("Click any cell to set it origin and start search"),
                                                             BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private MouseListener cellMouseListener(Cell cell) {
        return new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {solve(cell);}
        };
    }

    private List<Cell> getNeighbors(Cell cell){

        List<Cell> neighbors = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int row = (cell.getPosition().x -1) ;
                row <= (cell.getPosition().x +1) ; row++) {

            if(! validPosition (row,0)) { continue;}

            for(int col = (cell.getPosition().y -1) ;
                    col <= (cell.getPosition().y +1) ; col++) {
                if(! validPosition (row,col)) { continue;}
                if((row == cell.getPosition().x) &&
                        (col == cell.getPosition().y) ) { continue;}
                if((row != cell.getPosition().x) &&
                        (col != cell.getPosition().y) ) { continue;}
                neighbors.add(cells[row][col]);
            }
        }

        Collections.shuffle(neighbors);
        return neighbors;
    }

    private boolean validPosition(int row, int col) {

        return (row >= 0) && (row < mazeRows)
                                    && (col >= 0) && (col < mazeCols);
    }

    private Cell getSymetricCell(Cell cell) {

        if(! validPosition(cell.getPosition().x,
                cell.getPosition().y)) { return null; }
        int row = mazeRows - cell.getPosition().x -1;
        int col = mazeCols - cell.getPosition().y -1;
        return cells[row][col];
    }

    private Cell[][] getCells(int rows, int cols) {

        Cell[][] cells = new Cell[rows][cols];

        for(int row=0; row <cells.length; row++) {
            for(int col=0; col<cells[row].length; col++) {
                cells[row][col] = new Cell();
                cells[row][col].setPosition(row, col);
            }
        }

        return cells;
    }

    boolean solve(Cell cell) {
        reset();
        return dfs(cell);
    }

    boolean dfs(Cell cell) {

        if(cell == null){ return false; }
        //if cell is wall, or was explored
        if( !cell. isToBeExplored()) { return false; }

        Cell symCell = getSymetricCell(cell);

        if((symCell == null) || ! symCell.isToBeExplored()) { return false; }
        symCell.setState(State.WALL);

        cell.setState(State.WAS_EXPLORED);

        //loop over neighbors
        for(Cell c : getNeighbors(cell)){
            if (dfs(c)) {  return true; }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void reset() {

        for(Cell[] cellRow : cells) {
            for(Cell cell : cellRow) {
                cell.setState(State.EMPTY);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingMaze();
    }
}

class Cell extends JLabel {

    Point position;
    State state;
    private static int cellH =65, cellW = 65;

    Cell() {
        super();
        position = new Point(0,0);
        state = State.EMPTY;
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cellH , cellW));
        setOpaque(true);
    }

    boolean isToBeExplored() {  return state == State.EMPTY; }

    Point getPosition() {return position;}

    void setPosition(Point position) {this.position = position;}

    void setPosition(int x, int y) { position = new Point(x, y);    }

    void setState(State state) {
        this.state = state;
        setBackground(state.getColor());
    }

    State getState() { return state; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cell " + position.getX() + "-" + position.getY()+ " " + state  ;
    }
}

enum State {

    EMPTY (Color.WHITE), WALL (Color.BLUE), EXPLORED(Color.YELLOW),
    WAS_EXPLORED(Color.PINK);
    private Color color;

    State(Color color) {  this.color = color; }

    Color getColor() { return color; }
}
```

Clicking will set it as origin and start search. Click the same cell again to see different segmentation.

[image]

Comment: When I have time I will look at how to have it search for multiple solutions. It needs backtracking to do so. If you have another solution consider posting it for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a way to solve this problem, which is to search from the line dividing the grid, the code is as follows:

```
public class Maze {

int point[][] = new int[10][10]; // The intersection between the line and the line
int dir[][] = {{-1,0},{1,0},{0,-1},{0,1}}; // get Neighbors
static int N = 6; // default size 
static int count = 0; 

public void dfs(int x, int y) {
    if (x == 0 || y == 0 || x == N || y == N) {
        count++;
        return;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        int n = x + dir[i][0];
        int m = y + dir[i][1];

        if (n < 0 || n > N || m < 0 || m > N) { continue; }
        if (point[n][m] == 0) {
            point[n][m] = 1;
            point[N-n][N-m] = 1;
            dfs(n, m);
            point[n][m] = 0;
            point[N-n][N-m] = 0;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Maze test = new Maze();
    test.point[N/2][N/2] = 1; // Search from the center point
    test.dfs(N/2, N/2);
    System.out.println(count/4); // There are four types of rotational symmetry
} }
```